# Heuristics on the asymptotic behaviour of the divisor funcion

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, divisor-sum, riemann-hypothesis

Let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of divisor function. We know, by Gronwall's Theorem, that

$${\lim \text{sup}}_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log{n}} =e^\gamma$$

And the Riemann Hypothesis (Robin's Inequality) states that:

$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log{n}} <e^\gamma  \: \forall n>5040$$

But, regarding the following equality:

$$\sigma(n)-e^\gamma n \log \log{n}= O(f_1(n))$$

• Do we know anything about what is supposed to be $f_1(n)$?

• Do we have any (either formal or heuristic) argument to defend any special function?

• When trying to go beyond that $f_1(n)$, what would be the next step? Finding a function $f_2(n)$ such that

$$\sigma(n)-e^\gamma n \log \log{n}-f_1(n)= O(f_2(n))$$

? If so, do we know/believe anything about it?

• Do we know/believe at which "step" $k$ (if any) we would find something of the form:

$$\sigma(n)-e^\gamma n \log \log{n}-f_1(n)- \cdots -f_k(n)= O(1)$$
?

Comment: The appropriate comparison is not between $\sigma(n)$ and $n \log \log n$ but between $\sigma(n)$ and $e^\gamma n \log \log n$.  What text references are you using for your studies? Might I recommend Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory? It has many answers you are looking for.

Comment: Oops, a typo. I forgot about the factor. Thank you very much for the bibliography, I will take a look at it as soon as I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can show 
$$
\sigma(n) \le n e^\gamma \log \log n + O(n).
$$
On the other hand, when $n$ is prime, we have
$$
\sigma(n) = n+1.
$$
so, in fact, 
$$ n e^\gamma \log \log n -\sigma(n) = n e^\gamma \log \log n -n -1
$$
infinitely often. The sum of divisors function is too erratic to say anything more unless you want to talk about average orders.

Here is a plot of $\sigma(n)-e^\gamma n \log \log n$ for $n<10^5$.
[image]

Here is a plot of $\frac{\sigma(n)}{e^\gamma n \log \log n}$ for $n<10^5$.
[image]

Comment: And what about a lim sup instead of an average? And, by the way, is there any paper where I could read a proof of that $O(n)$? Thank you

Comment: One reference is Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory, , page 86.  I don't know what you mean by "what about a lim sup...?".  You have Gronwall's Theorem.

Comment: Sorry for missexpressing myselft. I meant an asymptotic behaviour of $$\sigma(n) -e^\gamma n \log \log{n} -cn$$ where c is the constant given by $$\text{lim sup}_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)-e^\gamma n \log \log{n}}{n}$$

Comment: What do you think the asymptotic behavior is? And what do you think the value of $c$ is?

Comment: Well, we could try to compute or plot the function, but when I posted my question I was thinking in an analytic approach rather than a computational one

Comment: What analytic approach have you tried? The computations and plotting are, for me, good ways to see what we might want to, and might reasonably try to, prove analytically.  What do you think the value of $c$ is?

Comment: Well, in fact, does the limit $$\text{lim sup}_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)-e^\gamma n \log \log{n}}{n}$$ exist? If so, it converges very slowly

Answer (score 3):

The 1984 article of Robin also contains the unconditional result, for $n \geq 3,$
$$ \sigma(n) \leq n e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{ n \cdot 0.64821364942... }{\log \log n},$$
with the constant giving equality at $n=12.$ The logarithms are natural.

Comment: Nice result there.

Comment: @MatthewConroy http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Robin_1984.pdf

Comment: @MatthewConroy I actually prefer the version of his adviser, Nicolas. Most people have trouble programming the superior highly composite numbers and experiments...The primorials are much easier to fiddle with http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Nicolas_1983.pdf

Comment: Thanks: these are nice references.  Cheers!

Comment: On the other hand, this bound means anything when talking about asymptotic behaviours, since we could also write $\sigma (n) \le n e^{\gamma} \log{\log{n}}+ e^{x}$

Comment: @user3141592 suggest you download and read the 1944 paper by Alaoglu and Erdos listed in the references at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number  Put briefly, the upper bounds of Robin are about the behavior of $\sigma(n)$ for colossally abundant numbers. Lower bounds are completely different, all we get is $\sigma(n) \geq n+1,$ with equality whenever $n$ is a prime number.

Comment: @user3141592  this page should be helpful when reading Alaoglu and Erdos  (1944) http://oeis.org/A073751   I recommend trying to program the CA numbers yourself. Part of such a program is to produce an ordered list of primes, exactly as here: http://oeis.org/A073751/b073751.txt   The easier part of the program is to read that list and simply perform the cumulative multiplications, producing the sequence of CA numbers.